# IndexOutOfBoundsException at android.graphics.Paint.native_measureText(Native Method)

Tags: android

I have an android app on Google Play and occasionally get the following error reported through the developer console / ACRA. The app runs fine on my test devices and on the various AVDs that I test it on.

The stack trace doesn't state where in the app the problem is. Is there anything I can do to narrow down where to look? What generally causes the error?

```
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at android.graphics.Paint.native_measureText(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.Paint.measureText(Paint.java:1020)
        at android.graphics.Paint.measureText(Paint.java:1057)
        at android.text.Styled.drawDirectionalRun(Styled.java:267)
        at android.text.Styled.measureText(Styled.java:430)
        at android.text.Layout.measureText(Layout.java:1518)
        at android.text.Layout.getHorizontal(Layout.java:564)
        at android.text.Layout.getHorizontal(Layout.java:548)
        at android.text.Layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(Layout.java:533)
        at android.widget.TextView$QuickAction.getBound(TextView.java:9550)
        at android.widget.TextView$QuickAction.show(TextView.java:9604)
        at android.widget.TextView$QuickActionController.show(TextView.java:8846)
        at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:8033)
        at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:9096)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller
        .run(ZygoteInit.java:895) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the look of this, you have a race in your application initialization block. Probably one of your text resources is not fully inflated before a draw is issued. (i know, the model of the android runtime should prevent this, but if this happens when the layout is calculated, it would be plausible).

Hope this is of some help in narrowing it down.